# Wait Operation Time Out

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I am working on a large database for health organization and it has millions of records.it is integrated with ASP.NET web application.unfortunately when saving a large form the "Wait Operation Time Out" error was occurring.

U have searched and found its the SQL Server error, so on solution I also found that the queries are taking so much and need to be optimized.SO i used the SQL Server tuning and performance tool by following its recommendation almost 100%. Luckily the error is occurring no more.

**ASK:**
I just need to confirm if it is a permanent solution or not? Also provide any better recommendations if you have.?

Thanks

Shahzad Ul hassan

Comment: Providing code snippet would be useful for people trying to help you

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to confirm if it is a permanent solution or not?

This is not a permanent solution and this can occur again..

> Also provide any better recommendations if you have.?

This has to be dealt on case by case basis..But normally this occurs when your query is not well tuned,stale statistics,missing indexes...

So rebuilding indexes regularly( We do it every weekday),will help in reducing the issue,if it still occurs,you will have to optimize the query

Answer (score 0):

I would also verify that the table is indexed optimally.  You can get a free tool called sp_BlitzIndex from Brent Ozar.
https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sql-server-downloads/

I would also make sure that Indexes and statistics are rebuilt at least on a weekly basis.  Ola Hallengren has a great maintenance solution that is free as well.
https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Good luck!